# Sending >1 GB arraybuffer using ajax to make a string file

Tags: ajax, arraybuffer, fileshare

I want to send a large arraybuffer using ajax to make a string file into local folder in my computer.

When im trying to send request using chrome console:

```
>  var arr = new Uint8Array(999999999);
>              arr[0]=[84]; // this is TEST TEXT
>              arr[1]=[69];
>              arr[2]=[83];
>              arr[3]=[84];
>              arr[4]=[32];
>              arr[5]=[84];
>              arr[6]=[69];
>              arr[7]=[88];
>              arr[8]=[84];


 function stringFromArray(data)
  {
    var count = data.length;
    var str = "";

    for(var index = 0; index < count; index += 1)
      str += String.fromCharCode(data[index]);

    return str;
  }

$.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:19885/binaryfile.bin' ,          
            cache: false,
            async: false,           
            type: 'POST',       
            data: '{Type: "File", content: "'+  stringFromArray(arr)+'"}',
            dataType: "json",           
            processData: false,       
           });
```

My browser crashed and i couldt create any file.
Any help?

Comment: Why would you do that? Heavy processing shoulnd't be done with Ajax nor the browser. Can't you do a php script called with the command line? (CLI)

Comment: you can send such data only by parts